# Loading specific data onto a jtable on a frame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, arraylist, jtable

[image: Screenshot of Frame design]

The screenshot above shows the current design of a frame, and this concept still is difficult for me to grasp: Adding data onto a table.

I've searched about the topic before, but I always saw that the code included the use of `Vector`s. I however, wish to use **no vectors**, and for this table, to be able to insert only a specific set of data.

For example, if the selected Activity is ***Bowling***

the method will run through a file called **students.dat**, which is in this format:

```
StudentName
Grade
Email
ParentName
ParentPhone
ParentEmail
Sunday
SundayActivity
Monday
MondayActivity
Tuesday
TuesdayActivity
Wednesday
WednesdayActivity
Thursday
ThursdayActivity
```

The method will return only the `StudentNames` `Grades` and `Parent Contact`& `ParentEmail` of the students who are involved in Bowling, as seen in the screenshot, into an `ArrayList`. From the moment the items are entered into the Arraylist, I do not know what to do onwards.

-Also, when loading into the ArrayList, I plan to do something like this:
`StudentNames` into `NamesList`, `Grades` into `GradeList`, etc to seperate each array

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Vectors then you need to create a custom TableModel because the DefaultTableModel was written to support Vectors or 2Dimensional arrays.

One way to do this is to copy the DefaultTableModel and change all the occurrences of Vector to ArrayList.

Or if you want to get fancy then you can use my version of a [List Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/list-table-model/).

Comment: Sorry but I'm still pretty new to java..if possible could you provide a pseudocode of some sort? I'm not exactly sure of what to do

Comment: Then use the DefaultTableModel and Vectors. Don't try to customize the default behaviour until you understand the basics. I suggest you read the JTable API and follow the link title "How to Use Tables" for some examples of using a JTable. I susupect your problem is more about reading the data from the file, but first you need to know how to load data statically, then you can try loading dynamic data.